# Android - Auto-Resizing

Tags: android, xml

I need the Button to stay on the right and then EditText box to automatically take up the rest of the space (re-size).

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
            <EditText android:id="@+id/PPL_Txt" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
                android:id="@+id/Button01" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try setting layout_width="fill_parent" on the EditText

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/PPL_Txt" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work, EditText takes up all the space and the button disappears.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the button to stay on the right then let EditText just wrap content?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:text="EditText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></EditText>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used layout weight to sort it, you have to play with it to get it to ratio correctly, apparently setting % like in CSS isn't available in Android.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/PPL_Txt" 
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="30"/>
                <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/Button01" 
                android:layout_weight="70" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Options">
                </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of along the lines of user576820: set the layout_width of the EditText to 0dp and layout_weight to 1. Leave the layout_width of Button to wrap_content and don't set a layout_weight (or set it to 0). That way, you don't have to guess about weight ratios.